# PHP Scope For Loop (or whatever issue it is)

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code:

```
function FirstFactorial($num) {
  $factorial = "$num";
  for ($i = $num - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $factorial += "*" . $i ;
  }
  return $factorial; 
}
echo FirstFactorial(6);
```

I've been trying to concatenate the expression into a string but I can't get it to work. In JS, I use similar code and it works as wanted (http://jsfiddle.net/w1x4cdeb/). What's wrong with this PHP?

Comment: `$factorial .= "*" . $i ;`

Comment: `implode(' * ', range($num, 1, -1));` ? [Example](http://3v4l.org/k2mch)

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this? Bad Tag

Comment: this really shouldn't have been hard to research!

Answer (score 2):

`+=` is addition, not concatenation. use `.=` instead.

The `+` operator is used for both in Javascript, but in many other programming languages (e.g. PHP and Perl) there are different operators for string concatenation and for addition.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function FirstFactorial($num) {
  $factorial = "$num";
  for ($i = $num - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $factorial .= "*" . $i ;
  }
  return $factorial; 
}
echo FirstFactorial(6);
```